# Combinations: If n players in team, each has to play x out of y games what is the maximum number of players one can have for all matches?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I think this can be solved with a combinations formula. But, not quite sure which formula to use.

Combinations: If n players can play on a team and all players have to play at least x out of y (y>x) games, then what is the maximum number of players one can have for all the matches together?

Example: If 12 players can play on a team and all players have to play at least 3 out of 4 games then what is the maximum number of players one can have for all the matches together?

The answer would be 16.

What would be a math formula to generalize this?

Comment: So something like $\dfrac {ny}{x}$ adjusted for rounding?

Comment: That's right. Can you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converted from comment as requested:*

If the squad of players is size $s$ then the proportion of matches they can play in on average is $\frac n s$.  This must be at least $\frac x y$ so $\frac n y \le \frac x y$, implying $s \le \frac{ny}{x}$ and since $s$ is an integer, you need to round down and its maximum possible value is $$\Big\lfloor\dfrac{ny}{x}\Big\rfloor$$